# How to add prefix to values in one column if not null using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame  in which I need to add prefix to rows from one of the columns if it's `not null`

```
   Name  marks
0   Tom     99
1  Jack     98
2  Nan     95
3  juli     90
```

how can I add the `prefix= "/new/"` to the column Name if not null?
so the New df will look like the following:

```
   Name       marks
0  /new/Tom    99
1  /new/ Jack  98
2  Nan         95
3  /new/juli   90
```

Answer (score 1):

like this I think

```
df['Name']=np.where(df['marks'].notna(),df['Name']+'/new/',df['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`add()` works out of box

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].add('/new/')
```

If it is string type `Nan`, you can use `mask` or `np.where`

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(df['Name'].ne('Nan'), df['Name'].add('/new/'))

# or

df1['Name'] = np.where(df1['Name'].ne('Nan'), df1['Name'].add('/new/'), df1['Name'])
```

Comment: Using pandas.DataFrame.add() will add the string to the ends of the rows of a column, it's not a prefix.

Comment: @LukaBanfi OP has edited his question.

Comment: I apologise, I wasn't paying attention.